# execute only some cells from a large jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I wanted to repeat an analysis included in a large jupyter notebook and save a couple of the generated dataframes in a csv file. My first attempt was to open the notebook in jupyter-lab and interactively run the cells I was interested, then add a new cell with my code that saves the relevant data to files.

I was wondering however if I could do the same thing with a script, e.g. run the 1st and 45th cell of the notebook and then run a few more commands to export the data.

Answer (score 0):

## cell 0

```
import IPython.display
```

## cell 1

```
x = 1
```

## cell 2

```
x = x + 1
print(x)
```

## cell 3

```
IPython.display.Javascript("Jupyter.notebook.execute_cells([2])")
```